# How to avoid and fix the warning from Graphite-manage?

Tags: linux, python

We installed Graphite on our Linux server, and when we started running it, we saw the following warning from the `graphite-manage` script:

```
 graphite-manage syncdb --noinput

 /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graphite/settings.py:246: UserWarning: 
 SECRET_KEY is set to an unsafe default. This should be set in 
 local_settings.py for better security
 warn('SECRET_KEY is set to an unsafe default. This should be set in 
 local_settings.py for better security')
 Creating tables ...
 Installing custom SQL ...
 Installing indexes ...
 Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s
```

How do you avoid this warning? What is needed to fix it?

Comment: May you extend on what you do not understand from the error message itself and what search/reading you did in graphite documentation which didn't solve the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

A `SECRET_KEY` has to be set in the `/opt/graphite/webapp/graphite/local_settings.py` file. More information could be found [here](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config-local-settings.html).